# extjs 5 how to bind multiselect to viewModel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm trying to bind a multiselect form field to a viewModel however it's not working.

```
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Groups',
        bind:'{myReference.selection.groupIds}',
        allowBlank: false,
        xtype:'multiselect',
        store: 'Groups',
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'label'
    }
```

Any id on how bind it to the selection?

Thx I really appreciate your help!

Comment: same problem with checkboxes. Not working either

Comment: Can you post your full code? Where is the viewModel property defined?

Comment: viewModel Property is assigned at the mainView since my bindings are using relationships. The Groups grid has the reference myReference. The field is from the GroupsForm form right next to it.